# linq get date from datetime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, gridview

I need to get date from datetime in linq like this:

```
var items = db.Students.ToList().Select(u => new { bi = u.Birthday.Date });
```

but items in grid are displayed as follows:

[image: grid]

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming Birthday is a string? What format is it in? You should really be storing Birthday as a DateTime object rather than as a string, it will make your life FAR easier. You can't reliably sort on that field if it is stored as a string for starters.

Comment: Why are you trying to generate a string instead of simply returning the date??? If you want to *format* the value for display, do so on your view or form, not your query. If you want to return only the date portion use `.Date`

Comment: What is `Birhday`'s type?

Comment: @GavinCoates Birthday is a datetime. I do not want convert to string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Birthday is a datetime. I edited my question.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman this question is not duplicate. I see very answer in stack. They did not solve my problem.

Comment: So you got the date, right? What is the problem with the outcome?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman I ask this question in better text see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241422/get-date-from-datetime-in-linq-and-show-gridview

Answer (score 4):

The Method `string.Format` can't betranslated into a SQL statement. But you can materialize the rows first `.ToList()` and `string.Format` afterwards.

```
var items = db.Students.ToList().Select(u => new { bi = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", u.Birthday) });
```

Comment: The power of Linq sometimes works against it ;-) It is so powerful you can't imagine there a things it can't do. But when working on non-.NET sources like SqlServer Linq sometimes just can't 'translate' the Linq to a SQl statement. The message "can't translate in a store expression" isn't really clear for that situation.

Comment: @Michel what do you mean? The error is *very* clear - you can't use String.Format and that's it. In fact, trying to format strings in SQL is a bad idea in general, even if a `FORMAT` function is available

Comment: Thanks for response but I need to date format to sort items.

Comment: I edited my question. I need to date format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I don't think that when you first encounter this problem (that Linq can't translate your Linq into Sql) that .NET makes a clear hint of that with the message "can't translate in a store expression"